# How to get back the set data when page reloads

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm writing a time management system for the BPO I'm working for while writing this kind of hit a wall. I tried searching but didn't find something that worked for me but based on what read I tried to do some stuff which eventually didn't work.

My problem is this, I'm using a date picker and an employee drop down to search for time details which they have entered with another form to the database. I use JavaScript to send the search variables and the create the PHP table which will show up in a `DIV` if the search was successful.

Below is my initial code:

Main search page

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once ("../Functions/userCheck.php");
?>

<html>
<head>

    <!-- Style Sheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css">

    <!-- Java Scripts -->
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/editTimeEntryFunctions.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/timeEditResultFunctions.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getUser.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getIds.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getCat.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getClient.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/getIds.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/reload.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/setMsg.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/sendData.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="getUser(); checkGetData();">
<div id="divCenter-timeEdit" class="box">
    <div class="logo-timeEdit">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv" style="height: 38px;">
        <label for="dPicker">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dPicker" style="margin-left: .5%;" size="10">
        <label for="userSelect" style="margin-left: 2%">Select User:</label>
        <select id="userSelect" style="width:160px; margin-left: .5%;" onchange="usrId(this.id);"></select>
        <input type="text" id="uid" size="1" hidden>
        <input type="button" class="getData" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">
    </div>
    <div id="resultTable"><span id="noDataMsg"></span> </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript

```
function getData(){

    var date = document.getElementById("dPicker").value,
        uid = document.getElementById("uid").value;

    if (date === ""){
        document.getElementById("noDataMsg").innerHTML = "Date not selected";
    }else if (uid === ""){
        document.getElementById("noDataMsg").innerHTML = "User not selected";
    }else{
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }else{

            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                document.getElementById("resultTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/timeEditResult.php?date="+date+"&uid="+uid,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

My function PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../iConnect/handShake.php");
include_once ("../Functions/userCheck.php");

if ($_REQUEST["date"] != "" && $_REQUEST["uid"] != ""){

//  Set data session to be used when page reloads to keep show the data intact in the table
    $_SESSION["date"] = $_REQUEST["date"];
    $_SESSION["uid"] = $_REQUEST["uid"];

//  Check if the there's any data in the database if there is it will be passed on to the query
    $getCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usertimetrack WHERE jDate = :jDate AND usrId = :usrId";
    $getCountQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getCount);
    $getCountQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
    $getCountQuery -> bindParam(':usrId', $_REQUEST["uid"]);
    $getCountQuery -> execute();
    $rowCount = $getCountQuery -> fetchColumn();

    if ($rowCount > 0){
//      This will select all the details in the database according to the entered data and the user who entered it
//      Which will be displayed as a table in the main PHP file.
        $getJobs = "SELECT usertimetrack.*, userlogin.uName, catdb.Catagory, clientdb.Client FROM usertimetrack
                    INNER JOIN userlogin ON usertimetrack.usrId = userlogin.uId
                    INNER JOIN catdb ON usertimetrack.Category = catdb.catId 
                    INNER JOIN clientdb ON usertimetrack.utClient = clientdb.clientId
                    WHERE jDate = :jDate AND usrId = :usrId";
        $getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getJobs);
        $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
        $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':usrId', $_REQUEST["uid"]);
        $getJobsQuery -> execute();
?>
<html>
<head>

<!--    <!-- Style Sheets -->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">-->
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css">-->
<!---->
<!--    <!-- Java Scripts -->
<!--    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>-->
<!--    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>-->

</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="navi"></div>
        <div id="infoi"></div>
        <table id="hor-minimalist-b" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 96%; margin-left: 2%;">
            <div id="bgDimmer"></div>
            <div id="divContent" style="width: 65%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: -8%;"></div>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Category</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Client</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Start Time</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">End Time</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Time Spent</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Volume</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Prod. Lines</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 16%;">Remarks</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($getJobsRow =$getJobsRow = $getJobsQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["uName"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Catagory"]; ?></td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word;"><?php echo $getJobsRow["Client"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["startTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["endTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["timeSpent"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Volume"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["noOfProductLines"]; ?></td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; text-align: left"><?php echo $getJobsRow["Remarks"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="utEdit" value="Edit" data-utid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" onmousedown="popup();" />
                        <input type="button" class="utDel" value="Delete" data-utid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" onmousedown="popup();" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <span id="noDataMsg">There's no data to display</span>
        <?php }}elseif($_SESSION["date"] != "" && $_SESSION["uid"] != ""){

        //  Check if the there's any data in the database if there is it will be passed on to the query
        $getCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usertimetrack WHERE jDate = :jDate AND usrId = :usrId";
        $getCountQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getCount);
        $getCountQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_SESSION["date"]);
        $getCountQuery -> bindParam(':usrId', $_SESSION["uid"]);
        $getCountQuery -> execute();
        $rowCount = $getCountQuery -> fetchColumn();

        if ($rowCount > 0){
        //      This will select all the details in the database according to the entered data and the user who entered it
        //      Which will be displayed as a table in the main PHP file.
        $getJobs = "SELECT usertimetrack.*, userlogin.uName, catdb.Catagory, clientdb.Client FROM usertimetrack
                    INNER JOIN userlogin ON usertimetrack.usrId = userlogin.uId
                    INNER JOIN catdb ON usertimetrack.Category = catdb.catId 
                    INNER JOIN clientdb ON usertimetrack.utClient = clientdb.clientId
                    WHERE jDate = :jDate AND usrId = :usrId";
        $getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getJobs);
        $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_SESSION["date"]);
        $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':usrId', $_SESSION["uid"]);
        $getJobsQuery -> execute();
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>

            <!--    <!-- Style Sheets -->
            <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/main.css">-->
            <!--    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../CSS/jquery-ui.min.css">-->
            <!---->
            <!--    <!-- Java Scripts -->
            <!--    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>-->
            <!--    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jScripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>-->

        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="mainDiv">
            <div id="navi"></div>
            <div id="infoi"></div>
            <table id="hor-minimalist-b" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 96%; margin-left: 2%;">
                <div id="bgDimmer"></div>
                <div id="divContent" style="width: 65%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: -8%;"></div>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">User Name</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Category</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Client</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Start Time</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">End Time</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Time Spent</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Volume</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Prod. Lines</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 16%;">Remarks</th>
                    <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php while ($getJobsRow =$getJobsRow = $getJobsQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["uName"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Catagory"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word;"><?php echo $getJobsRow["Client"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["startTime"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["endTime"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["timeSpent"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Volume"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["noOfProductLines"]; ?></td>
                        <td style="word-wrap:break-word; text-align: left"><?php echo $getJobsRow["Remarks"]; ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" class="utEdit" value="Edit" data-utid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" onmousedown="popup();" />
                            <input type="button" class="utDel" value="Delete" data-utid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" onmousedown="popup();" /></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php }else{ ?>
                <span id="noDataMsg">There's no data to display</span>
            <?php }}else{ ?>
            <span id="noDataMsg">User or date not selected</span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I use this table to edit or to delete listed data this where have the problem. Once deleted or Edited the main table stays the same I want to refresh the page and update the existing table with out redoing the initial date and user selection. I did try the below codes which I learned after searching but I think I'm not doing it right.

Reload JavaScript

```
function resetForm2() {
    justBeforeReload();
    window.location.reload();

}

function justBeforeReload() {
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        sessionStorage.setItem("date", $('#dPicker').val());
        sessionStorage.setItem("date", $('#uid').val());
    }
}
```

I'm missing the retrieval code I wrote sorry about that (fury delete) the above code pieces are called when the blow functions are executed.

```
//Timed process for updating user time entries
function tEditReload() {
    timeSheetAdd();
    setTimeout("setMsg();",100);
    setTimeout("closeForm();",5000);
    setTimeout("resetForm2();",1000);
}

function delTimeProcess() {
    delTimeEntry();
    setTimeout("setMsg();",1000);
    setTimeout("closeForm();",2000);
    setTimeout("resetForm2();",1000);
}
```

I know the post is long but wanted give a clear idea what I'm trying to do basically I want update table with the same selected search variables on the reload.

Can come one please show me light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question because I really didn't get an answer to my question which is fairly very long. After posting my initial problem I waited for 48 hours to see if I get an answer which would direct me down the right path but only answer was posted by @Michal Salacinski thank you for taking your time to answer.

So here is what I did (All the coding is original and was cooked up by me).

I wanted to keep the search criteria as is and to load the same data with the updated data. First I tried doing it with sessions and JavaScript which almost draw me crazy.

Then I thought of doing it with PHP, MySQL and JavaScript and yes I've to say I succeed.

What I did first is, I create a table which will hold all the search queries and then created a MySQL task to truncate the table every day at 00.00 Hours. Then I split my main PHP display code in to two see the below code.

```
<?php if ($_SESSION["sT"] == "Done"){ ?>
<body onload="tEditReload2()">
<div id="divCenter-timeEdit" class="box">
    <label id="sbId" hidden><?php echo $_SESSION["uRole"]?></label>
    <div class="logo-timeEdit">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv" style="height: 38px;">
        <label for="dPicker">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dPicker" style="margin-left: .5%;" size="10" value="<?php echo $getStermRow["sDate"]; ?>">
        <label for="userSelect" style="margin-left: 2%">Select User:</label>
        <select id="userSelect" style="width:160px; margin-left: .5%;" onchange="usrId(this.id);"></select>
        <input type="text" id="uid" size="1" value="<?php echo $getStermRow["sUid"]; ?>" hidden>
        <input type="button" class="getData" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">
    </div>
    <div id="resultTable"><span id="noDataMsg"></span> </div>
</div>
</body>
<?php }else{?>
<body onload="getUser();">
<div id="divCenter-timeEdit" class="box">
    <label id="sbId" hidden><?php echo $_SESSION["uRole"]?></label>
    <div class="logo-timeEdit">
        <img src="../../images/logo.png" width="142" height="33">
    </div>
    <div id="mainDiv" style="height: 38px;">
        <label for="dPicker">Date:</label>
        <input type="text" id="dPicker" style="margin-left: .5%;" size="10">
        <label for="userSelect" style="margin-left: 2%">Select User:</label>
        <select id="userSelect" style="width:160px; margin-left: .5%;" onchange="usrId(this.id);"></select>
        <input type="text" id="uid" size="1" hidden>
        <input type="button" class="getData" value="Submit" onclick="getData();">
        <input type="button" value="cookie" onclick="readCookie();">
    </div>
    <div id="resultTable"><span id="noDataMsg"></span> </div>
</div>
</body>
<?php } ?>
```

Below is the code I use to set the initial session for a `$_SESSION["sT"]`.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["sT"])){
    $_SESSION["sT"] = "No";
}
```

The above code PHP will make sure the correct `if` conditions met and the correct HTML be displayed.

Then I use 2 functions in my body onload.

1. Which will just load the data to populate the drop down where users get to select the user names.

   function getUser()
   {
       if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
       else
       {
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }

   ```
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
       if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
       {
           document.getElementById("userSelect").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
   };
   xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/getUsrId.php?uid=getUsr",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
   ```

   }
2. I use a timed function to run 2 functions one of which loaded the users for the drop down while keeping the selected user when the initial search happened and the other ran the function to retrieve the search data from the server.

Timed function,

```
function tEditReload2() {
    getUser2();
    setTimeout("getData();",100);
}
```

Get data function,

```
function getData(){

    var sbId = document.getElementById("sbId").innerHTML,
        date = document.getElementById("dPicker").value,
        uid = document.getElementById("uid").value;

    if (date === ""){
        document.getElementById("noDataMsg").innerHTML = "Date not selected";
    }else if (uid === ""){
        document.getElementById("noDataMsg").innerHTML = "User not selected";
    }else{
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }else{

            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                document.getElementById("resultTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/timeEditResult.php?date="+date+"&uid="+uid+"&sbId="+sbId,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Then used the below code to set of PHP code to add the search terms to the temp table then to update the session so the correct HTML would be run on the reload and after that same code will pull the data from the database with an inner joined query.

```
if ($_REQUEST["date"] != "" && $_REQUEST["uid"] != ""){

//  Add Search terms to search term database to retrieve later
    $addSearch = "INSERT INTO searchterm(sDate,sUid,searchedBy) VALUES (:sDate, :sUid, :sb)";
    $addSearchQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($addSearch);
    $addSearchQuery -> bindParam(':sDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
    $addSearchQuery -> bindParam(':sUid', $_REQUEST["uid"]);
    $addSearchQuery -> bindParam(':sb', $_REQUEST["sbId"]);

    if ($addSearchQuery -> execute()){
//      Get's the last entered search ID
        $lastSid = $dbConnect -> lastInsertId();
        $_SESSION["lSid"] = $lastSid;

        $_SESSION["sT"] = "Done";
    }else{
        $_SESSION["sT"] = "Not";
    }

//  Check if the there's any data in the database if there is it will be passed on to the query
    $getCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usertimetrack WHERE jDate = :jDate AND usrId = :usrId";
    $getCountQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getCount);
    $getCountQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
    $getCountQuery -> bindParam(':usrId', $_REQUEST["uid"]);
    $getCountQuery -> execute();
    $rowCount = $getCountQuery -> fetchColumn();

    if ($rowCount > 0){
//      This will select all the details in the database according to the entered data and the user who entered it
//      Which will be displayed as a table in the main PHP file.
        $getJobs = "SELECT usertimetrack.*, userlogin.uName, catdb.Catagory, clientdb.Client FROM usertimetrack
                    INNER JOIN userlogin ON usertimetrack.usrId = userlogin.uId
                    INNER JOIN catdb ON usertimetrack.Category = catdb.catId 
                    INNER JOIN clientdb ON usertimetrack.utClient = clientdb.clientId
                    WHERE jDate = :jDate AND usrId = :usrId";
        $getJobsQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getJobs);
        $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':jDate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
        $getJobsQuery -> bindParam(':usrId', $_REQUEST["uid"]);
        $getJobsQuery -> execute();
```

Below HTML draws the results table generated by the above PHP.

```
<body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <div id="navi"></div>
        <div id="infoi"></div>
        <table id="hor-minimalist-b" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 96%; margin-left: 2%;">
            <div id="bgDimmer"></div>
            <div id="divContent" style="width: 65%; margin-left: 20%; margin-top: -8%;"></div>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">User Name</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Category</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">Client</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Start Time</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">End Time</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Time Spent</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Volume</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 6%;">Prod. Lines</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 16%;">Remarks</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php while ($getJobsRow = $getJobsQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["uName"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Catagory"]; ?></td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word;"><?php echo $getJobsRow["Client"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["startTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["endTime"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["timeSpent"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["Volume"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $getJobsRow["noOfProductLines"]; ?></td>
                    <td style="word-wrap:break-word; text-align: left"><?php echo $getJobsRow["Remarks"]; ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="button" class="utEdit" value="Edit" data-utid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" onmousedown="popup();" />
                        <input type="button" class="utDel" value="Delete" data-utid="<?php echo $getJobsRow["utId"]; ?>" onmousedown="popup();" /></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <span id="noDataMsg">There's no data to display</span>
        <?php }}else{ ?>
            <span id="noDataMsg">User or date not selected</span>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Now I faced some problem with populating the drop down and the date picker text area so the below code part was created.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["lSid"])){
    $getSterm = "SELECT searchterm.*, userlogin.fName, userlogin.lName FROM searchterm
                 INNER JOIN userlogin ON searchterm.sUid = userlogin.uId WHERE sId = :sId";
    $getStermQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getSterm);
    $getStermQuery -> bindParam(':sId', $_SESSION["lSid"]);
    $getStermQuery -> execute();
    $getStermRow = $getStermQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

After the data was added I used the above mentioned timed function to get the data and to retrieve the data from the data base.

I was facing some issue with the drop down which was resetting it self to an empty item when the page get reloaded. This was caused by a PHP and the javascript running together.

So I solved the problem by making the below java script and modifying the PHP which pulled the data from the user login table.

JavaScript,

```
function getUser2(){

    var selUser = document.getElementById("uid").value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("userSelect").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/getUsrId.php?uid=getUsr2&selUser="+selUser,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PHP which I rewrote with an `if .. else`,

```
//Get user details from the data base and populate the user select drop down
if($_REQUEST["uid"] == "getUsr"){
    $getUsr = "SELECT * FROM userlogin ORDER BY uId ASC";
    $getUsrQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getUsr);

    echo "<option></option>";
    while ($row = $getUsrQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option id= ".$row["uId"].">".$row["fName"]." ".$row["lName"]."</option>";
    }
}else{
    $getUsr = "SELECT * FROM userlogin ORDER BY uId ASC";
    $getUsrQuery = $dbConnect -> query($getUsr);

    $getSelUsr = "SELECT * FROM userlogin WHERE uId = :uid";
    $getSelUsrQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getSelUsr);
    $getSelUsrQuery -> bindValue(':uid', $_REQUEST["selUser"]);
    $getSelUsrQuery -> execute();
    $getSelUsrRow = $getSelUsrQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo "<option id= ".$getSelUsrRow["uId"].">".$getSelUsrRow["fName"]." ".$getSelUsrRow["lName"]."</option>";
    while ($row = $getUsrQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        if ($row["uId"] == $_REQUEST["selUser"]) continue;
        echo "<option id= ".$row["uId"].">".$row["fName"]." ".$row["lName"]."</option>";
    }
}
```

After doing this I got what I wanted (yEy to me). I know this might not have been the best way to go about this problem but I managed to get it working the way I wanted.

I would like to hear what improvements can be done to this also like to say if any one want to use the code please feel free to use it.

I would like to thank the StackOver flow community for helping a lot in learning new stuff and helping me to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling "resetForm2" directly, there's no need to create "onbeforeunload" here. just make something like:

```
function resetForm2() {
  sessionStorage.date = $('#dPicker').val();
  sessionStorage.uid = $('#uid').val();
  window.location.reload();
}


function getData(ssd,ssid){

    var date = ssd?ssd:document.getElementById("dPicker").value,
        uid = ssid?ssid:document.getElementById("uid").value;

    if (date === ""){
        document.getElementById("noDataMsg").innerHTML = "Date not selected";
    }else if (uid === ""){
        document.getElementById("noDataMsg").innerHTML = "User not selected";
    }else{
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){

            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

        }else{

            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                document.getElementById("resultTable").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("POST","../functions/timeEditResult.php?date="+date+"&uid="+uid,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
window.addEventListener("load",()=>if(sessionStorage.date&&sessionStorage.uid)getData(sessionStorage.date,sessionStorage.uid))
```

Not tested but you should be able to get it working.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as you say I can set the variables but function `getData()` doesn't get called when the page reloads I written it as a button click event. But the upper part of your answer kind of lit a small LED bulb in my mind hope it grows. Can you tell me is there way to check if the session is set or not using java script.